# TipKit not accessible in even on Xcode 15 beta 2

Tags: swift, swiftui, xcode15, ios17

link - https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10229/?time=0

I came across an interesting video from Apple's WWDC 2023 conference,
titled "**Discovering New Features with TipKit**."

It seems like `TipKit` is a new framework that enables developers to explore and utilize the latest features in their apps.

I tried to `import TipKit` into my project, but unfortunately, I am not able to import it. if there are any additional dependencies or frameworks that need to be imported to access TipKit successfully.

If you have any suggestions or resources to help me explore TipKit further, I would greatly appreciate it. Feel free to share any relevant links or insights.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: it's not available yet (as at 15.2 Beta)

Comment: have to wait then, thanks for clarification @flanker

Answer (score 1):

TipKit was made available in Xcode 15 beta 5.